# How do I make car acceleration in my game?

Tags: game-engine, physics

I also want to know how to make my car accelerate. Here are my nodes in logic:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My car uses Dynamic physics because Character ones make the car shake all the time...

Comment: I've tried it before but never seem to figure out how to work it. I tried to use force. To make my car turn or go forward or backward I could easily apply a button to my logic brick and all that to make my car do different things.

Comment: It would be most likely helpful if you can write down all the logic bricks names, what they do and the math and such, I could help you since i've done crazy things like make a tank shoot giant missiles from its cannon and explode on target. Anyway, I can help you on the chat if you like. Just let me know you'll be their.

Comment: @7Blue_Beast7 Do they help you? If so, I can make .blend for you so you can play with them...;) But it requieres 2.72 or higher...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure if this is how you will like it, but I have a different idea. As you press W, the car's property 'accelerate' will increase. If the property is from interval 0-40; the property will have +6 added every time you hit W (with frequency: 10); the same applies for 41-80; 81-120; etc. It will add less in lower interval, and higher as it goes. For more realism, you can make a lot of intervals where it will add less to the 'accelerate' property when it is at a high speed. Now, when you hold W, the property will add as it looks like acceleration. All that is left is to bind it with however you have done your motion, such as "the car goes x fast if interval is from z to y," just play around with the values. You can do a very similar technique for deceleration. I have a GIF that is uploading right now of the logic bricks. I will add it to this answer ASAP.

GIF: http://recordit.co/Ahw2QIeaLu
-The intervals in the gif are very ruggid, they are: 0-40, 41-80, 81-120. For a racing game, you would want it much smoother, so you may have to do by tens or even five so it can be perfected. When you open the webpage for gif, just pay attention to debug properties.

Comment: I was wondering why GIF looked a little funny, I didn't do 41-80 for the middle one, I think I did 21-80 by mistake. With that in mind, it is an easy fix.

Comment: OK! Thanks... It looks helpful, but I got other question- how do I make it, so it tests for propertie's value and makes speed automaticly basing on it. Also, how to make speed increase slower on top speeds? And the most important- how do I make inertia, so car continues path after releasing W key?

Comment: I will try inverting W key and removing property for inertia, but I still need to put it together... I dont know how to make car move in this situation

Comment: OK! I relooked trought evrything nad figured out how to make it work- it really helped- thanks!:)

Comment: I need help- I need someone to make me Windows runtime game, cause I can make only linux runtime game...

Comment: Sorry I was late, but if you figured it out then that is great. If you didn't put inertia, you still can have it. All you need to do is make a function for deceleration, which is very similar, and make the car always go the speed of the value; therefore, W will only be used to add speed, not holding W will remove speed, and the car's speed follows the property. I have also found a bug, the car's speed can exceed 220 and reach 222, and if you add deceleration, it can exceed 0 and reach -4. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I will show you what I made- here you can download and see all bug fixes;) https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7xeh4cucqnmd3j/6th_gear.blend?dl=0

Comment: cool gif, but how do you actually apply these values to motion actuators or acceleration script?